# How to keep asking the same question until a specific input has been entered

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aXYp.png)

such as the image above, the code will keep asking for a mark and storing that in a variable. Until the user has entered -1 it won't stop. And then adding up all the inputs entered for the average mark

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop

```py
while True:
  n = int(input('Please enter a mark out of 100:'))
  if n == -1:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this:

```
while True:

    answer = int(float(input("please enter a mark out of 100: ")))
    #this way you keep asking while the answer doesn't match a condition        

    if answer < 0:  #check if your objective has been completed

        break #if condition matchese you stop the loop
    
#do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
right_answer = 'Potato'
while True:
    answer = input("Put the Question here: ")
    if answer == right_answer:
        break
    else:
        print('More code')
```